# mb_detect_encoding does not detect SJIS-mac?

Tags: php, character-encoding, php-7.2

I have a csv file in SJIS encoding.

When I call `mb_convert_encoding($contentOfFile, 'UTF-8', 'SJIS-mac')`, the UTF-8 output is correct.

But when I use `mb_detect_encoding($contentOfFile, ['SJIS-mac', 'SJIS-win', 'SJIS', 'UTF-8'])` ,  it always returns SJIS-win.

PHP version: 7.2.11

```
<?php

$utf8Str = "❶❷❸❹❺";

$sjisStr = mb_convert_encoding($utf8Str, 'SJIS-mac');

echo(mb_detect_encoding($sjisStr, ['UTF-8','SJIS-win', 'SJIS-mac', 'SJIS']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in PHP's mbstring extension, which I am just fixing. (It was quite interesting to discover your question just as I am working on fixing the bug!)

Comment: Fixes for SJIS-mac have now been merged into the mainline and should become part of PHP 8.1.